# How to parse a JSON file from HTML into Python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, json, parsing

I have an HTML page with various information, like:

```html
<input class="json-data" id="init-data" type="hidden" value='{"keyboardShortcuts":[{"name":"xxxx","description":"yyyyy", > etc...
```

How can I obtain something like

```
name = xxxx
```

That is my code so far, but every time it just prints None:

```
content = page.read()
html = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = html.find("input", class_="json-data", value_="keyboardShortcuts")
```

Comment: `value_="keyboardShortcuts"` doesn't match the element you've shown, that's only *part* of the value. Why not use the `id`? Also note that you'll have to parse the JSON from the value to get things like the `name` value.

Comment: So how would you do it? This is the first time I am doing something like this and I am a bit lost.

Comment: The BS4 docs will tell you how to get the element by ID, and how to access the value of an element's attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull out the `value` attribute, read using `json`, then you can get the value for the `name` key:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
import json

content = '''
<input class="json-data" id="init-data" type="hidden" value='{"keyboardShortcuts":[{"name":"xxxx","description":"yyyyy"}]}
'''

html = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
jsonData = json.loads(html.find('input', {'id':'init-data'})['value'])

print (jsonData['keyboardShortcuts'][0]['name'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (jsonData['keyboardShortcuts'][0]['name'])
xxxx
```